# Как расположить 2 FAB в WebView - Flutter, Android

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile-development

Всем привет, прошу сильно не пинать, только изучаю Flutter, одновременно практикуясь на своём первом проекте. Теперь к самому вопросу: возможно ли расположить поверх WebView несколько Fab (одна кнопка в нижнем левом углу, а другая в нижнем правом)? Как "грамотно" это сделать? Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: null,
        ...
      ),
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: null,
        ...
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```